# how to format my computer, wipe out windows, and set it with only ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, windows, format

I am absolutely new to linux and don't know a whole lot about this, but I'm trying to learn!

I already looked through old questions and it seems that usually the installation of Ubuntu offers the option of replacing the old windows instead of running Ubuntu alongside it, but I never got that option.  Because my computer is a two year old netbook and is getting super slow, I would like to format it and run only one OS, just need it for the basics (School, email, music...).

So now, I have both Ubuntu (I think its 12.04.3 LTS) and Win 7 Starter on my computer, how should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear. You already have Ubuntu along with Windows if my understanding is correct. Then login every time in to Ubuntu. If you just want more disk space you need not reinstall the whole OS. All that you need to do is take the data backup and delete windows partition and reformat them. But when you boot, it will still show you that it can boot into Windows but if you select that option, it will not boot. That can also be fixed using the below commands.

Check 
`sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/30_custom` or `sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom`. You should find the windows booting sequence. Remove the windows related items, save and close. After that run the below command to update the grub.
`sudo update-grub2`

This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you need to bring out the big guns. Use [Darik's Boot And Nuke](http://www.dban.org/download) to zero out the drive and MBR. Then rerun the Ubuntu installer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the liveUSB (I'm presuming that you did use the liveUSB to install 12.04.3 in the first place), then, when the installer comes up, there would be 3 options. You can install Ubuntu alongside Windows, completely replace the Win system or you could create a custom partition table using gparted(supported out of the box in the liveUSB). Choose the option where you could completely replace Windows, and the installer would do the rest. It'll format your entire disk to the ext format,install all that is necessary, and that's about it, you'd be good to go after that.